# How to change the generated Directory Id for Wix using heat?

Tags: wix, heat

I am using heat to generated wix files for multiple directories.

However, it seems like if Directory A and Directory B has the same folder name, even though the absolute path is different, heat still think that it is the same directory, therefore generates the same directory Id.

There seems to be a way of fixing that, is to override the generated Directory Id by using -directoryid, but there are no examples given in the manual, how are we suppose to pass in the arguments. Obviously, somehow it needs to know which Directory Id I wanted to change, I will very much appreciate it if someone could help.

Thanks.

http://wix.sourceforge.net/manual-wix3/heat.htm

Comment: I also met the same issue, got blocked by duplicated Directory ID. Wxs output file is the same with or without `-directoryid`, and looks like there is no a tiny snippet of example out there :(

Comment: As far as I understand, -directoryId parameter is intended to change the root directory element generated and it won't help you with overriding some of the descendant directories. You may experiment with replacing it with -dr parameter.

Answer (score 1):

Overriding the output from heat pretty much always falls back to applying an XSLT to get the output the way you want.