# WiX - How to have different copy strategies during installation

Tags: wix

During installation, my application will:

Step A, Look for `C:\WebService` directory. If found do following:

```
copy *.bat      --> C:\WebService\
copy boost*.dll --> C:\WebService\libs\
copy myApp.dll  --> C:\WebService\plugins\
```

Step B, If not found, do following:

```
copy *.bat --> [LocalAppData]\myApp\bin\
copy *.dll --> [LocalAppData]\myApp\libs\
```

How can I do this?

**EDIT:**

I had finished Step 2 by:

1. Create a source directory:

   `src\bin`
   `src\libs`
2. Copy files to these subdirs
3. Use `heat` to scan the src directory and generate group into wxs file.

The problem here is, looks like for Step A, I have to do the same again. But there are tons of *.dll, copying them again to another directory doesn't look like a good idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, finally worked it out.

In short, I do this by writing a C++ program to help.

Details follows..

My wxs starts like:

```
<Directory Id='TARGETDIR' Name='SourceDir'>
  <Directory Id='WebDir'>
      <Directory Id='INSTALLDIR' Name='$(var.ProductName)'/>
  </Directory>
  <Directory Id='DefaultDir'/>
</Directory>
```

Now use `heat` to harvest my source directory to generate another wxs file for `candle` and `light` to link

Then goes my C++ program, it was designed to

1. Scan the whole generated wxs file to create another directory structure.
2. Replace all IDs of Directories, Components and Files to make them unique.
3. Generate new GUIDs for all new components.
4. Gather all new component IDs to create a new component group.

This new component group can be referenced to be installed conditionally, depends on whether there is a registry key, or whether the directory is found, in my case it is:

```
  <Feature Id='RuntimeChrome' Level='1'>
    <Condition Level='0'>NOT INSTALLDIR_REGCU AND NOT INSTALLDIR_REGLM</Condition>
    <ComponentGroupRef Id='WebGroup' />
  </Feature>
  <Feature Id='RuntimeDefault' Level='1'>
    <ComponentGroupRef Id='DefaultGroup' />
  </Feature>
```

With these wxs files, the package can be installed into different places under different scenarios.

Answer (score 3):

The way you phrase the problem indicates that there is a huge gap in your understanding of Windows Installer.  MSI / WiX isn't a scripting language.  You need to understand how AppSearch, Features, Directorties, Components and Conditions work.  Basically you need to group your files into components and use AppSearch to detect whether the directory exists.  Then use the result of that search in conditions to decide which files get installed.

Comment: Edited my question with a little more details, sorry for my ignorance

Comment: Just found that your solution will be blocked by duplicated directory id - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8539762/how-to-change-the-generated-directory-id-for-wix-using-heat

Comment: I didn't give you a solution, I told you what to read up on.  I have no idea what your code looks like but if you have duplicated directory ID's  consider putting the Directory element in a fragment and using DirectoryRef elements  to use them in other fragment files.