# WiX - How to change name of a directory after installation

Tags: wix

Pretty simple question, suppose my app will be installed as

```
myApp
 +-- bin
 +-- lib
```

I'd like to rename "lib" to "plugins" after installation, how can i do that?

There is a [MoveFiles Element](http://wix.sourceforge.net/manual-wix3/wix_xsd_movefiles.htm) that might help, but no idea how to use it.

**EDIT:**

The problem here is, in my case, source files could be installed into different paths, this scenario described in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11967316/wix-how-to-have-different-copy-strategies-during-installation).

The only way I can figure out is to create two component groups and install them conditionally. However, using `heat` to harvest same subdir twice will cause [ID conflicting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8539762/how-to-change-the-generated-directory-id-for-wix-using-heat), so I'm thinking to use different paths(e.g. `lib` and `another-lib`), and then rename one of the path back after installation, so this question arised...

Comment: You can apply an XSLT to `heat` output and rename the directories there. However, if the files have to be put into the same directory on installation, you better harvest that same image. Can't you copy libs before harvesting with heat?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally wrote a C++ program to extend `heat` generated wxs with another directory structure. So we can decide which path to install under different situations. It worked just like changing name during installation.

Here is the wxs file patched by my program. Basically it creates another directory `WEBIDR` and different subdirs, then adds another component group `webGroup` for later reference by condition element.

You can do the same thing manually, but if there are thousands of files awaiting, and if they are frequently updating, maybe a program(or script) is a better choice.

```
<Fragment>
    <DirectoryRef Id="INSTALLDIR">
        <Directory Id="dirA5528701EE26FFBF346CCE20EE8ACE99" Name="bin">
            <Component Id="cmpEBA9C2A32D81BA8646BD1A64DBB39DB1" Guid="{142C531A-C71C-4890-9318-0FC42026C8FC}">
                <File Id="filDB56E052EC783676CEF361C0C5AA71F3" KeyPath="yes" Source="$(var.runDir)\bin\boost_date_time-vc100-mt-1_47.dll" />
            </Component>
        </Directory>
        <Directory Id="dir3279BEF4E08D9A00D2F205F325F00A81" Name="modules">
            <Component Id="cmpDECCAE13F8937500E4AC367A8EAC95F4" Guid="{85CC0C94-1BFB-4062-BC4E-FBF143921301}">
                <File Id="filDD3B40D68D0437B18B1108FBA49ABC1B" KeyPath="yes" Source="$(var.runDir)\modules\HelloAPI.dll" />
            </Component>
        </Directory>
    </DirectoryRef>
    <DirectoryRef Id="WEBDIR">
        <Component Id="webcmpEBA9C2A32D81BA8646BD1A64DBB39DB1" Guid="{fec110c5-a1a0-4b07-8a35-50f1af84001a}">
            <File Id="webfilDB56E052EC783676CEF361C0C5AA71F3" KeyPath="yes" Source="$(var.runDir)\bin\boost_date_time-vc100-mt-1_47.dll" />
        </Component>
        <Directory Id="webdirpluginF4E08D9A00D2F205F325F00A81" Name="plugins">
            <Component Id="webcmpDECCAE13F8937500E4AC367A8EAC95F4" Guid="{3ef79a47-7681-4991-9726-02db38c22f6d}">
                <File Id="webfilDD3B40D68D0437B18B1108FBA49ABC1B" KeyPath="yes" Source="$(var.runDir)\modules\HelloAPI.dll" />
            </Component>
        </Directory>
    </DirectoryRef>
</Fragment>
<Fragment>
    <ComponentGroup Id="runGroup">
        <ComponentRef Id="cmpEBA9C2A32D81BA8646BD1A64DBB39DB1" />
        <ComponentRef Id="cmpDECCAE13F8937500E4AC367A8EAC95F4" />
    </ComponentGroup>
    <ComponentGroup Id="webGroup">
        <ComponentRef Id="webcmpEBA9C2A32D81BA8646BD1A64DBB39DB1" />
        <ComponentRef Id="webcmpDECCAE13F8937500E4AC367A8EAC95F4" />
    </ComponentGroup>
</Fragment>
```

Answer (score 3):

Don't. Install the files correctly up front. The way that the Windows Installer tracks things will fight you every step of the way. Just install the files in the correct folder from the beginning. Probably not the answer you wanted.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Had updated my question with more details